# Database doesn't update with FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin

I'm trying to install SonataAdminBundle in my Symfony2 application and seems to work fine except UserBundle. It is not updated in the database.
When I do:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:info
```

it throws me the next:

```
[OK]   HoHa\UserBundle\Entity\User
[OK]   Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser
[OK]   Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseGroup
```

And yes, it is mapped. But the fields are not created (except id).
Look at my entity User.php:

```
<?php

namespace HoHa\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
#I've also tried: use Sonata\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;


public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    // your own logic
}

}
```

Why User is not extended when I update the database?
FOSUserBundle shows the login and register page, and Sonata shows login page too.

When I do:

```
$ php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

I get:

```
Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.
```

This is my app/config/config.yml file:

```
imports:
        - { resource: parameters.yml }
        - { resource: security.yml }
        - { resource: @HoHaHomeBundle/Resources/config/admin.yml }

    framework:
        #esi:             ~
        translator:       ~
        secret:          %secret%
        router:
            resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
            strict_requirements: ~
        form:            ~
        csrf_protection: ~
        validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
        templating:
            engines: ['twig']
            #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
        default_locale:  "%locale%"
        trusted_proxies: ~
        session:         ~
        fragments:       ~
        http_method_override: true

    # Twig Configuration
    twig:
        debug:            %kernel.debug%
        strict_variables: %kernel.debug%

    # Assetic Configuration
    assetic:
        debug:          %kernel.debug%
        use_controller: false
        bundles:        [ ]
        java: /usr/bin/java
        filters:
            cssrewrite: ~
            #closure:
            #    jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar
            yui_css:
                jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor.jar
            yui_js:
                'jar': %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor.jar

    # Doctrine Configuration
    doctrine:
        dbal:
            driver:   %database_driver%
            host:     %database_host%
            port:     %database_port%
            dbname:   %database_name%
            user:     %database_user%
            password: %database_password%
            charset:  UTF8
            # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
            # e.g. database_path: %kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3
            # path:     %database_path%
            types:
                json: Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType

        orm:
            auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
            #auto_mapping: true
            entity_managers:
                default:
                    mappings:
                        HoHaUserBundle: ~
                        SonataUserBundle: ~


    # Swiftmailer Configuration
    swiftmailer:
        transport: %mailer_transport%
        host:      %mailer_host%
        username:  %mailer_user%
        password:  %mailer_password%
        spool:     { type: memory }

    sonata_block:
        default_contexts: [cms]
        blocks:
            sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
                contexts:   [admin]

            #sonata.admin_doctrine_orm.block.audit:
            #    contexts:   [admin]

            sonata.block.service.text:
            sonata.block.service.rss:

            # Some specific block from the SonataMediaBundle
            #sonata.media.block.media:
            #sonata.media.block.gallery:
            #sonata.media.block.feature_media:
    fos_user:
        db_driver:      orm
        firewall_name:  main
        user_class:     HoHa\UserBundle\Entity\User

        group:
            group_class: HoHa\UserBundle\Entity\Group

    sonata_admin:
        templates:
            dashboard: SonataAdminBundle:Core:dashboard.html.twig
```

and my app/config/security.yml file:

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
        SONATA:
            - ROLE_SONATA_PAGE_ADMIN_PAGE_EDIT  # if you are using acl then this line must be commented

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                    admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }
        fos_userbundle:
             id: fos_user.user_manager
             #id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        # -> custom firewall for the admin area of the URL
        admin:
            pattern:            /admin(.*)
            context:            user
            form_login:
                provider:       fos_userbundle
                login_path:     /admin/login
                use_forward:    false
                check_path:     /admin/login_check
                failure_path:   null
            logout:
                path:           /admin/logout
            anonymous:          true

        # -> end custom configuration

        # defaut login area for standard users

        # This firewall is used to handle the public login area
        # This part is handled by the FOS User Bundle
        main:
            pattern:             .*
            context:             user
            form_login:
                provider:       fos_userbundle
                login_path:     /login
                use_forward:    false
                check_path:     /login_check
                failure_path:   null
            logout:             true
            anonymous:          true
        login:
            pattern:  ^/demo/secured/login$
            security: false

        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/demo/secured/
            form_login:
                check_path: _security_check
                login_path: _demo_login
            logout:
                path:   _demo_logout
                target: _demo
            #anonymous: ~
            #http_basic:
            #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"

    access_control:
        # URL of FOSUserBundle which need to be available to anonymous users
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

        # Admin login page needs to be access without credential
        - { path: ^/admin/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/logout$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/login_check$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

        # Secured part of the site
        # This config requires being logged for the whole site and having the admin role for the admin part.
        # Change these rules to adapt them to your needs
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN] }
        - { path: ^/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

The file app/logs/dev.log gives me the next:

```
[2013-08-26 17:40:27] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT TABLE_NAME AS `Table`, NON_UNIQUE AS Non_Unique, INDEX_NAME AS Key_name, SEQ_IN_INDEX AS Seq_in_index, COLUMN_NAME AS Column_Name, COLLATION AS Collation, CARDINALITY AS Cardinality, SUB_PART AS Sub_Part, PACKED AS Packed, NULLABLE AS `Null`, INDEX_TYPE AS Index_Type, COMMENT AS Comment FROM information_schema.STATISTICS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'fos_user' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'hoha' [] []
```

Answer (score 1):

I Know, old question, however I just had this very same problem.
For me the solution was to add the following to bundles Appkernel:

new Sonata\EasyExtendsBundle\SonataEasyExtendsBundle(),

new Sonata\UserBundle\SonataUserBundle('FOSUserBundle'), // the 'FOSUserBundle' is optional

After that I ran into a new problem, I got a [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]  Unknown column type "json" requested ....
This was fixed by the following in config.yml

doctrine:

```
dbal:       
    types:
        json: Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType
```

Hope this helps anybody.

Answer (score 0):

In your `app/config/config.yml`, try setting FOSUserBundle User class to your own.

```
fos_user:
    <...>
    user_class: Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User # Your class here
```

Source: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#step-5-configure-the-fosuserbundle

Comment: Actually, we are extending `FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser`. Maybe that will help. Also, try extending FOSUserBundle by using `SonataEasyExtendsBundle` command. Also, try extending `Sonata\UserBundle\Model\User` first. When this works, move to FOSUserBundle

Comment: Well, you can see under "use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;" that I've tried with "use Sonata\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;". Extend FOSUserBundle by using SonataEasyExtendsBundle? I prefer not to change the third party bundles, since it is supposed that you can extend them in your own bundles.

Comment: I offered you to extend `Entity`, not `Model`. And SonataEasyExtendsBundle only extends a given bundle, not changes it.

Comment: Ok. But Entity neither works. In fact, the doc says to put Model. How is it suppossed to extend SonataEasyExtendsBundle?

Comment: I've found this error in app/logs/dev.log: "./app/logs/dev.log:[2013-08-27 10:46:43] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception ReflectionException: "Class Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User does not exist" at /home/manolo/MiServer/HoHa/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/AbstractManagerRegistry.php line 199 {"exception":"[object] (ReflectionException: Class Application\\Sonata\\UserBundle\\Entity\\User does not exist at /home/manolo/MiServer/HoHa/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/AbstractManagerRegistry.php:199)"} []"

Answer (score 0):

In my case, xml had preference over annotations in the ApplicationSonataUserBundle.

I renamed Resources/config/doctrine by Resources/config/doctrine.bak and the User.php in ApplicationSonataUserBundle is now my Entity.